# C Prevent more than 30 character input

Tags: c

Hi I'm having an issue with my code. I need it to run so that if the user enters more than 30 characters for the "fileName" variable it will "return;" but the code I have below doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
FILE *packetFile; //initialize file handle
char fileName[30]; //initialize
int i;
int length = 0;

length = strlen(fileName);
getchar();

printf("Please enter a file name (Maxium 30 characters): ");
fgets(fileName, 30, stdin);
sscanf(fileName, "%s", fileName);

if(fileName[0] == '\n'){
    return;
}

if(strlen(fileName) > 30)
    return;

if((packetFile = fopen(fileName,"w"))==NULL) {

    printf("Unable to open the file: %s\n",fileName);

} else {

    printf("%d packets have been saved to file named %s", pCount, &fileName);

    for(i=0;i<pCount;i++) {

     fprintf(packetFile,"%04i:%04i:%04i:%04i:%s\r\n",pRecords[i].source,pRecords[i].destination,pRecords[i].type,pRecords[i].port,pRecords[i].data);

    }

        fclose(packetFile);

}
```

Comment: You should make it more clear what it is that doesn't work as you'd expect/like.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple reasons. You're only allocating room for 30 characters, so a `strlen` will never return a result `> 30` in your case. You're also only reading max 30 chars in your `fgets` call.

A possible fix is to allocate more space to begin with and use `strlen`. Another solution is to keep the limited allocation, and use a loop to read individual characters from `stdin` - if you don't reach a newline character in time, you just break out and return.

On POSIX systems, `getline` provides a neat solution. It reads a whole line, and it returns the length. Only thing to remember is that `getline` allocates memory on the heap, so you need to free it when you're done.

Something along the lines of:

```
char *filename = NULL;
size_t linecap = 0; // These initial values tells getline to allocate as much space as needed
ssize_t linelen = getline(&filename, &linecap, stdin);
if (linelen < 0)
    ...
if (linelen > 30)
    // Treat as error or whatever

free(filename);
```

(shameless borrowing from the man page)

Comment: Brilliant. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: do I need to include any special libraries for that @Henrik

Comment: @Henrik  Note: `getline()` in not a standard function in C, but I think it is in POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

```
    char fileName[30+2];//+1 for '\n', +1 for '\0'
    int i;
    int length = 0;

    printf("Please enter a file name (Maxium 30 characters): ");
    fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin);

    if(fileName[0] == '\n'){
        return;
    }
    length = strlen(fileName);
    if(fileName[length-1]!='\n'){
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Given that there exist unusual cases where `length` is 0, Do you think is useful to do `if(length && fileName[length-1]!='\n'){` to prevent UB?

Comment: @chux If the length that you entered in fgets becomes 0. entered EOF?

Comment: Do not be content if strlen who received EOF in fgets if because it is garbage. So I to to guard the value of strlen(length) is no meaning.

Comment: Agree about `fgets()` returning NULL means garbage in `filename`.  `fileName[0]` can be `\0` with piped `stdin` or keyboard that allow entering `\0`.  `fgets()` stops on `\n`, but not on `\0`.  Also if `sizeof(filename)` was 1 - not in your case though.

Comment: @chux Do you to do so is to enter a file name? What for?

Comment: In creating test scripts with automated testing, use re-directed IO input to `stdio` and when this rare event happens (usually a bad test script), the code can fail dramatically.  especially when length is `size_t`, an `unsigned`.

Comment: I think the tests are stupid, it was good to fail in advance. It's around screaming attention such time a person uses the fgets is that a hard work.

Comment: I was wrong about garbage in `fgets()` on EOF.  On EOF the buffer contents are  unchanged.  On an IO error, the contents are indeterminate.  In those 2 cases, NULL was returned.

Comment: perhaps some people should make sure the return value of fgets, but I will not mention one by one.